# Save Custom Dictionary to User default

Tags: ios, swift, nskeyedarchiver

```
struct AllItemsData {
    var DSTBID: String!
    var CCAS: String!
    var BCAS: String!
}
```

This is my structure from which I create an array of type 
`AllItemsDataArray = [AllItemsData()]`

After adding some data, now I want to store it into user defaults.

I did it this way:

```
AllItemsDataArray.removeFirst()

let archivedArray = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: All_ItemsDataArray)
            print(archivedArray)
            preference.set(archivedArray, forKey: allItemsDataKey)
```

But the error is like:

> ios[1540:537869] -[_SwiftValue encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15d1e200

The values in the array just before the crash happens is:

> AllItemsData(DSTBID: GGGGGGGGGGGG, CCAS: , BCAS: )
>   AllItemsData(DSTBID: HHHHHHHHHHHH, CCAS: , BCAS: )

Comment: Your struct doesn't conform to the `NSCoding` protocol.

Comment: yeah :( its a pity that a struct never conform to NSCoding - i am also looking to a nice solution for this - how to save and restor a struct (and nested struct) from and to UserDefaults

Comment: on struct you get a `error: non-class type 'AllItemsData' cannot conform to class protocol 'NSCoding'` so you never have a chance to implement `NSCoding` :(

Comment: you need to change to a class

Comment: but i am waiting for a better solution

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement NSCoding protocol for you object, and use `class` instead of `struct`

```
class AllItemsData: NSObject, NSCoding {
    var DSTBID: String!
    var CCAS: String!
    var BCAS: String!

    required convenience init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        let DSTBID = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("DSTBID") as? String,
        let CCAS = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("CCAS") as? String,
        let BCAS = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("BCAS") as? [String]

        self.init(
            DSTBID: DSTBID,
            CCAS: CCAS,
            BCAS: BCAS
        )
    }

    func encodeWithCoder(coder: NSCoder) {
        coder.encodeObject(self.DSTBID, forKey: "DSTBID")
        coder.encodeObject(self.CCAS, forKey: "CCAS")
        coder.encodeInt(Int32(self.BCAS), forKey: "BCAS")
    }
}
```

Comment: you forget to say that he need to change it into a class. mot anymore by value - now by reference.

Comment: You have the wrong signature if this is supposed to be Swift 3.

Comment: Yeah for swift3 it should be "encode(with coder: NSCoder)"